# How to insert values into a junction table without knowing the id of the reference table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, junction-table

I have three tables: `releases`, `dependencies` and `release_dependencies`. Each `release` can have multiple `dependencies` which are thus store in a junction table called `release_dependencies`.

When inserting the dependencies for a release I know the `release_id` but I don't know the id of a `dependency`. The `dependency_id` could already exist in the database or I may have just found that dependency. A `dependency` has a unique index on the type, name and version and the to be inserted `release_dependencies` knows this. But I need that index to be turned into an id. Here's an example in Javascript to maybe make my question a bit more clear:

```
import knex from "knex";
import {randomUUID} from 'crypto';

const db = knex({
    client: 'mysql2',
    debug: true,
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'app',
        port: 33061,
        timezone: '+00:00',
    }
});

const releaseId = randomUUID();

const dependencies = [
    {
        id: randomUUID(),
        name: 'cors',
        version: '3.0.5',
        type: 'npm',
    },
    {
        id: randomUUID(),
        name: 'express',
        version: '5.0.4',
        type: 'npm',
    }
];

const releaseDependencies = [
    {
        id: randomUUID(),
        release_id: releaseId,
        dependency_id: 'npm-cors-3.0.5',
        parent_dependency_id: 'npm-express-5.0.4',
        is_dev: false
    },
    {
        id: randomUUID(),
        release_id: releaseId,
        dependency_id: 'npm-express-5.0.4',
        parent_dependency_id: '',
        is_dev: false
    }
];

await db
    .insert(dependencies)
    .into('dependencies')
    .onConflict()
    .ignore();

await db.destroy();
```

As you can see I'm inserting `dependencies` which will be ignored if it already exists. But now I want to insert my `release_dependencies` but it does not know the id of the dependency its referring to. Whats the best way to solve this?

My current solution is making a dependencyLookup from the `dependencies` table, but that means I have to load all dependencies into memory. I have thought of another solution which is the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO `release_dependencies` (`id`, `release_id`, `dependency_id`, `parent_dependency_id`, `is_dev`)
VALUES ('581b4262-b25f-477a-a151-2fa07c37e5a7',
        'a30bc721-6323-4d28-a4b3-a90400e4231a',
        (SELECT `id` FROM `dependencies` WHERE Concat_ws('-', type, name, version) = ?),
        (SELECT `id` FROM `dependencies` WHERE Concat_ws('-', type, name, version) = ?),
        false);
```

What is the best way to handle my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO `release_dependencies` (`id`, `release_id`, `dependency_id`, `parent_dependency_id`, `is_dev`)
SELECT '581b4262-b25f-477a-a151-2fa07c37e5a7',
       'a30bc721-6323-4d28-a4b3-a90400e4231a',
       id,
       id,
       false
FROM `dependencies`
WHERE (type, name, version) = (?, ?, ?);
```

That uses a syntax called *tuple comparison*, where all three columns must match the respective parameter.

If you need to match multiple dependencies, you can use tuple comparison with `IN()`. Just like any other `IN()` predicate, you must have as many parameters as you have values.

```
...
WHERE (type, name, version) IN ( (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) );
```